# Cannot access Google App Engine in browser

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-app-engine-python

I am making an application on Google App Engine, and want to run the app locally and test requests with Postman. I start the server locally with:

```python
python3 main.py
```

I then get the following:

```python
* Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 257-782-471
```

I can view the app perfectly using "web preview" and "preview on port 8080".
When i click on the link " http://127.0.0.1:8080/ " , it redirects me to  " https://8080-dot-12856039-dot-devshell.appspot.com/?authuser=0&environment_name=default " that works, but i cannot access this in postman.

When i type in http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in the web browser or in Postman, i get no response and a **The site is not available error**

When i deploy the application the URL and everything works fine, but i dont want to deploy the whole application each time i want to check something with requests. I just want to run it and access it locally.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you are providing, I assume that you are running the `python3 main.py` command in the Cloud Shell.

Then when you click on `Web Preview` or `Preview on port 8080`, this is creating an SSH tunnel from your Cloud Shell to the Virtual Machine that is hosting the resources behind the scenes, and this process is allowing you to connect and test the app by navigating either to `127.0.0.1:8080` or  `https://8080-dot-12856039-dot-devshell.appspot.com/?authuser=0&environment_name=default`.

In short, if you want to issue `GET` or `POST` requests, you can open another tab in the Cloud Shell and use curl in order to achieve the similar behavior you are trying with Postman. With Postman you are trying to access from outside and you don't have access to the URL.

This information is explained in the Cloud Shell [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview#previewing_the_application).